# How to write a python file just generated by the program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how do I write something in python file my program is generating.
Here we have : **hey.py** and **main.py**.
In hey.py there is :

```
import main

start = f"print('Hello {NAME}')\n print('or world')",
```

In the main.py I have :

```
import hey

NAME = input("Before starting , what is your name ? \n")
    namefile = input("okay , what should be the main file title ? \n")
    with open(namefile+".py", 'w') as f:
        f.write('{}'.format(start))
```

I would like to find in my python file just generated :

```
Hello Josh
or world
```

But unfortunately, my program can create the file but can't write in it :/

It's saying :

```
f.write('{}'.format(start))
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

Start is defined in hey.py. I imported. Have you any solution? Thanks for answering.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish? Mixing code and data should generally be avoided, especially if you are a beginner.

Comment: You need to use `hey.start` or `from hey import start` to access a global variable from another module.

Comment: Also note that your generated file will not have the `Hello Josh\nor world` that you expect, but rather the full `print` statements as specified in the `start` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems:

1. If importing like you have here, you need to use `main.NAME` and `hey.start`.
2. You're importing `hey.py` from `main.py`, and `hey.py`imports `main.py`. When a script is imported in Python, it is essentially run from top to bottom. This means that `hey.start` is only defined in `hey.py` after `main.py` is run, but `main.py` requires variables local to `hey.py`, specifically `hey.start`. The line that defines this variable hasn't been executed by the time `main.py` needs it.

Solution for the second problem is to remove `import main` and define

`start = "print('hello {}')\n print('or world')"`

instead. Then the formatting can be done in `main.py` as
`f.write(hey.start.format(NAME)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can be useful for you.

```
def create_file(namefile, text):
   pyfile = open(namefile,'r+')
   pyfile.write(text)
   pyfile.close()

create_file('example.py', 'print("{}")\nprint("{}")'.format('Hello Jhon','I am Joao from Peru'))
```

then run example.py